# How to find duplicate letters and remove all of them from a string in a list

Tags: python, string, duplicates

Given a list of names:

```py
name_list = ['Jasonn', 'pPeter', 'LiSsa', 'Joanna']
```

I want to remove the same letters(case insensitive), say for `name_list[0]`, it will be `'Jaso'` and for name_list[3], it will be `'Jo'` since after `'n'`s are removed, `'a'`s should also be removed.

Here's my code:

```py
i = 0
for name in name_list:
    ind = name_list.index(name)
    length = len(name)
    for i in range(0,length-1):
        if name[i].lower() == name[i+1].lower():
            name = name_list[ind].replace(name[i], '', 1)
            name = name.replace(name[i], '', 1)
            length -= 2
            if i >= 1 and name[i].lower() == name[i-1].lower():
                name = name_list[ind].replace(name[i], '', 1)
                name = name.replace(name[i-1], '', 1)
        else:
            i += 1
    if ind != len(name_list): 
        print(sep,end='', sep='') #sep is my separator
print()
```

My code does not compile. It fails on this line:

```py
if i >= 1 and name[i].lower() == name[i-1].lower():
```

with:

```
IndexError: string index out of range
```

I can't figure out why the range is wrong. My first thought was to check if the index is bigger than 0 so that `i-1` would not be negative. For example, given the string `'pPeter'`, after I removed `'pP'`, I then just check the new letter `'e'` for `i = 0` and `'t'` for `i+1` since there's no letter before index 0.

and for 'J[0]o[1]a[2]n[3]n[4]a[5]'

1. When `i = 3`, the `'n'`s for `i` and `i+1` are removed. The string then becomes 'J[0]o[1]a[2]a[3]'.
2. Since `i = 3 > 0` and both `i-1` and `i` equals `'a'`, we remove the `'a'`s and generate `'Jo'`.

Could someone help me figure out where I went wrong?

Comment: Would it work to put the `i = 0` inside the loop? Where it is, it's not going to reset for each name.

Comment: @blunova That doesn't answer this question. They're similar, but they're not the same.

Answer (score 3):

This approach looks unnecessarily complex.

Instead, you can keep track of the frequencies of every letter in the list. Then, retain only the letters that appear exactly once:

```py
from collections import Counter

name_list = ['Jasonn', 'pPeter', 'LiSsa', 'Joanna']
result = []

for name in name_list:
    letter_freqs = Counter(name.lower())
    result.append(''.join(letter for letter in name if letter_freqs[letter.lower()] == 1))

print(result)
```

This outputs:

```py
['Jaso', 'tr', 'Lia', 'Jo']
```

Comment: Wow it really is a concise answer! But if could, I still like to know where did my original code go wrong, thanks!

Comment: I'm not too sure, but even if it were to be fixed, it'd still be quite slow. Repeated replace operations can take a long time if the string is long.

Answer (score 1):

With regular expressions:

```
from re import sub, IGNORECASE

name_list = ['Jasonn', 'pPeter', 'LiSsa', 'Joanna']
result = []
for name in name_list:
    name2=name
    while True:
        name2=sub(r'(\w)(\1)', '', name, flags=IGNORECASE)
        if name2 == name:
            result.append(name2)
            break
        else:
            name = name2
print(result)
['Jaso', 'eter', 'Lia', 'Jo']
```